# handle error and log message in console javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, handle

i have the array with the numbers `[1, 2, 3]`.

> Create function `hs` that takes this array as parameter and then displays elements of this array on the screen. Use the loops is prohibited. This function has to validate an input parameter, because function can accept only a non-empty array.

```
f(1,2,3) // Error: parameter type should be an array
```

Comment: What part of "Error: parameter type should be an array" do you not understand? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Helps us answer better

Comment: You haven't asked a question about the code you've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code bellow

```
function hs(array, ...args) {
    if(args && args.length > 0) {
       console.log('The function takes only one input');
    } else if (!array || !Array.isArray(array)) {
       console.log('parameter type should be an array');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and avoid the `...` rest parameter, then just check `if (arguments.length !== 1)`. Since this looks to be for a homework problem, extra points for being thorough, but in general I think counting arguments is overkill - most production codebases would be happy with just the truthiness/`.isArray()` checks.